# Textarea filling vertical space

Tags: html, css, textarea

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G9cSZ/108/) illustrates the layout I am looking to have. The section which is giving me trouble is the css

```
#A_2_1_1, #A_2_1_2 {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}

#A_2_1_3 {
    background: yellow;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#A_2_1_3_1 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

When `#A_2_1_3_1` is a `div`, as it is in the fiddle, everything is good: `#A_2_1_3` fills the remaining vertical space of `#A_2_1`, but does not overflow it. However, when `#A_2_1_3_1` is changed to a `textarea`, this is no longer true: there is an overflow (see [fiddle with textarea](http://jsfiddle.net/G9cSZ/109/)).

How do I prevent this overflow from happening? I want this textarea to fill the remaining vertical space.

Comment: Like http://jsfiddle.net/Dipak1991/G9cSZ/110/ ??

Comment: One kind sugggestion.. Use css classes to style elements.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, as the top two `div`s have `float` values they are ignored while showing the third div as it has no `float`. Hence the third div starts from the top. But a `textarea` is not a container element like a `div`, hence it starts where the two `div`s end, and as it has `height: 100%`, it has the same height as the third div and the containing div (the third div) has to expand to accommodate the `textarea`.

Use `top` and `bottom` css attributes.
Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3Cwdr/

```
<div id="A">
    <div id="A_1">This is the header content.</div>
    <div id="A_2">
        <div id="A_2_1">
            <div id="A_2_1_1" style="background-color: yellow;">This is other stuff.</div>
            <div id="A_2_1_2" style="background-color: yellow;">This is more stuff.</div>
            <div id="A_2_1_3" style="height: auto; bottom: 0; position: absolute; top: 200px;">
                <textarea id="A_2_1_3_1" style="background-color: yellow;">Hi</textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This solution considers `A_2_1_1` and `A_2_1_2` `div`s have fixed heights.

Comment: Add `border: 0px` to make it perfectly ;)

Comment: i know i can do this, but i'd prefer to not need a specific value for top, which is why i was trying to use the floats.

Comment: also do you know why precisely textarea behaves differently than div in this situation?

Comment: @P5Coder thanks. I guess another solution is to just use a contenteditable div instead of a textarea here. (Edit: although now that I look it up, it seems contenteditable divs aren't really convenient at all.)